# How to receive Facebook Deep Link data

Tags: android, facebook, deeplink

In `AndroidManifest` I have

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
            android:host="linhtestdeeplink"
            android:scheme="app"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In `MainActivity`

```
AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(this,
        new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(final AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                // Process app link data
                Log.i("TAG", "Deep link receive" + appLinkData);
            }
        }
);
```

In `Facebook` page, I test Deep Link like

[image]

My app received a notification, when I click at the notification it will launch my app but the  `appLinkData` always `null`.
I also send like `linhtestdeeplink://tripId=1` but it also null.
Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.
I am using facebook sdk 4.5  `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'`

Comment: is it possible to post complete code / link ?

Answer (score 4):

Deep link format is `<scheme>://<host>` so your deep link should look like this: 
`app://linhtestdeeplink?tripId=1`